# WooCommerce Attributes Validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On Variable product page when you click on Add to Cart without selecting any attribute it will show you an alert like this

[Default alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqSA5.png)

So instead of this alert I wanted to show a message that a particular attribute is not selected or a group of attribute is not selected.

For example,

1. If color is not selected then it should show `Please select a color.`
2. If color and size are not selected then it should show `Please select a color and size.`

**I have tried a workaround to achieve with jQuery**

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('.disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).is('.wc-variation-selection-needed')) {

            var empty_variations = [];

            $('form.variations_form.cart').find('table.variations tr').each(function( index ) {
                var $variation_label = $(this).find('td.label');
                var $variation_value = $(this).find('td.value');

                var $variation_dd = $('select', $variation_value);
               
                if( $variation_dd.val() == '' || $variation_dd.val() == null ){
                    var label_text = $('label', $variation_label).text();
                    empty_variations.push( label_text )
                }

            });
            
            if( empty_variations.length != 0 ){
                alert( 'Please select ' + empty_variations.join(', ') + '.'); 
                return false;
            }            
        }
    }   
});
```

However anyone can let me know a standard way to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no WooCommerce hook available that can be used to modify the default action of the alert notification that appears if required attributes are not selected.

The hook that is related to validating product attributes before adding them to the cart is the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`. However, it is not applicable for modifying the alert message.

Therefore, using jQuery to catch the click event of the "Add to Cart" button and display a custom error message is the optimal way to achieve the requirement.

The code given in the question is not working and [is giving this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaaHL.png) ( Yes, I use it inside `jQuery( document ).ready()` with Woo-Commerce Version 7.5.1, Storefront theme Version: 4.2.0 ) . So, I made some changes to make it work, and this is my jQuery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // Find the add to cart button
  const addToCartButton = $('button.single_add_to_cart_button');

  // Override the default WooCommerce behavior
  addToCartButton.on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is('.disabled.wc-variation-selection-needed')) {
      // Find all the attribute selectors
      const attributeSelectors = $('.variations select');

      // Check if any of them have not been selected
      const missingAttributes = attributeSelectors.toArray().filter(function (selector) {
        return selector.value === '';
      }).map(function (selector) {
        return $(selector).parent(".value").siblings(".label").children('label').text().replace(/[:\n]/g, '').trim();
      });

      // If any attribute has not been selected, prevent default behavior and show custom alert
      if (missingAttributes.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Please select the following product options: ' + missingAttributes.join(', ') + '.');
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[Result of my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmFGz.png)